# Fatal error: Call to undefined function stats_cdf_normal()

Tags: php, azure-sql-database

I am calculating percentage from zscore(mean,standarddeviation) while doing this I am getting the exception

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function stats_cdf_normal()

I tried every possible solutions from google but not helpful.

I am using PHP 5. I am deploying my application on Azure cloud.

Comment: So if you tried __every__ possible solution, how can we help?)))

Comment: Did you install the Statistics PHP Extension. It does not come with normal PHP so you have to add it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/stats.setup.php